# Android AR Toolkits

Tags: android, mobile, augmented-reality

I have been looking around for a good Android AR toolkit to play with. I have found a few references but I am not really sure which ones to try. It seems to be a lot of work just to get any demo's working.

My requirement is that I want to be able to detect AR Markers/Tags. I would then look to add a 3D model based on the orientation of the marker/tag. A nice basic cube would be a great start :D

So do any of you have any recommendations?

I have just tried http://code.google.com/p/andar/ and it is not too bad. I would really like one that has some better project examples and well documented source code.

Oh, and as this is currently only for playing with I don't want to be paying any money for it.

Comment: Think of this site as a reference book, not a social site. "Hi All" and such would add lots of clutter to a million entries.

Comment: @cdhabecker, Thanks for the tip. But what are the rules for removing "Hi All,"? is it the comma at the end of the first line?

Comment: I don't know; probably depends on which monkey is on duty. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try looking at [NyARToolkit](http://nyatla.jp/nyartoolkit/wiki/index.php?NyARToolkit%20for%20Android.en)